# PyGame won't install on my Macintosh?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, python-3.4

I'm trying to install Python on my Macbook Air, but when I select my HD, the following error message pops up:

> "pygame 1.9.1 release can't be installed on this disk. pygame requires system Python 2.7 to install."

This might be a silly question, but is it because I have Python 3.4.1 installed?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have Python3.4, Python2.7 should still be here.

BTW, I have the same error with this file :
http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg

You have to use this link :
http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip
(Works on my Mac OS X Yosemite)

But you have to use Python2.7 to be able to use PyGame.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.__version__
'1.9.2pre'
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Pygame with Python 3 using instructions on this page:

https://jamesfriend.com.au/installing-pygame-python-3-mac-os-yosemite